# Parsing a JSON Object with multiple Sub-Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.stackmob.com/js/2.5.3-crypto-sha1-hmac.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$j.ajax({
        dataType : 'json',
        url : "/api/core/v2/groups/", //or any other rest call here
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            var bytes = Crypto.charenc.Binary.stringToBytes('username' + ":" + 'password');
                    var base64 = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(bytes);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic " + base64);
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            console.log("success!");
            console.log(data);
                        console.log(data[0]);
        }
    });
```

The output of `data` is

```
Object
    data: Array[25]
        0: Object
            contentTypes: Array[4]
            creationDate: "2012-05-31T20:21:20.532+0000"
            creator: Object
            description: "A discussion group for anyone interested in amateur radio."
            displayName: "amd-amateur-radio-forum"
            followerCount: 5
            groupType: "OPEN"
            id: 1133
            memberCount: 3
            modificationDate: "2012-06-04T21:23:07.078+0000"
            name: "AMD Amateur Radio Forum"
            resources: Object
            type: "group"
            viewCount: 62
            __proto__: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
        3: Object
```

but when I try to output `data[0]` or `data[1]` they all come back as `undefined`.
I am not sure how to deal with this JSON object.

The output of `alert(data)` is

```
[Object object]
```

so I am assuming it is a properly formatted JSON object.

Here is the output JSON.stringify(data)

```
{"data":[{"contentTypes":["discussions","documents","blog","projects"],"memberCount":3,"creator":{"name":"firstname lastname","level":{"name":"Level I","description":"null","points":7,"resources":{"image":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/images/status/statusicon-47.gif","allowed":["GET"]}}},"username":"dkyle","email":"david.kyle@amd.com","firstName":"firstname","lastName":"lastname","resources":{"self":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/users/4183","allowed":["GET"]},"avatar":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/users/4183/avatar","allowed":["GET"]}},"id":4183},"groupType":"OPEN","name":"AMD Amateur Radio Forum","displayName":"amd-amateur-radio-forum","description":"A discussion group for anyone interested in amateur radio.","followerCount":5,"resources":{"projects":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1133/projects","allowed":["GET"]},"invites":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1133/invites","allowed":["POST"]},"documents":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1133/documents","allowed":["GET","POST"]},"html":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/groups/amd-amateur-radio-forum","allowed":["GET"]},"self":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1133","allowed":["GET"]},"blog":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/blogs/1368","allowed":["GET"]},"members":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1133/members","allowed":["GET"]},"discussions":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1133/discussions","allowed":["GET","POST"]}},"id":1133,"type":"group","creationDate":"2012-05-31T20:21:20.532+0000","modificationDate":"2012-06-04T21:23:07.078+0000","viewCount":62},{"contentTypes":["discussions","documents","blog","projects"],"memberCount":34,"creator":{"name":"firstname lastname","level":{"name":"Level I","description":"null","points":24,"resources":{"image":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/images/status/statusicon-47.gif","allowed":["GET"]}}},"username":"username","email":"kristi.fontenot@amd.com","firstName":"firstname","lastName":"lastname","resources":{"self":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/users/4291","allowed":["GET"]},"avatar":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/users/4291/avatar","allowed":["GET"]}},"id":4291},"groupType":"OPEN","name":"AMD Community Corps Connect (Matching Gifts, GIVE and Volunteerism)","displayName":"amd-community-corps-connect-matching-gifts-give-and-volunteerism","description":"Through this community, employees are be able to support the causes they care about most in ways thev have never been able to before. Not only that, employees will be able to connect and network with fellow AMD employees in a way that allows everyone connected to each other to volunteer together, while providing the ability to track volunteer hours, make charitable contributions and request a match all in the same tool.  \r\n\r\nhttp://amd.yourcause.com \r\n\r\n","followerCount":55,"resources":{"projects":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1074/projects","allowed":["GET"]},"invites":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1074/invites","allowed":["POST"]},"documents":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1074/documents","allowed":["GET","POST"]},"html":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/groups/amd-community-corps-connect-matching-gifts-give-and-volunteerism","allowed":["GET"]},"self":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1074","allowed":["GET"]},"blog":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/blogs/1267","allowed":["GET"]},"members":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1074/members","allowed":["GET"]},"discussions":{"ref":"http://connect-dev.amd.com/api/core/v2/groups/1074/discussions","allowed":["GET","POST"]}},"id":1074,"type":"group","creationDate":"2012-05-07T19:24:31.880+0000","modificationDate":"2012-09-07T02:00:51.821+0000","viewCount":544}
```

It is actually longer than that

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in? You may need to use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js to parse it before you try and use it. And why are you doing crypto on the client side?

Comment: Do `alert(JSON.Stringify(data));` so you can see the contents of the object, and copy/paste that here for us

Comment: How does your data object look when you log it ??

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS It would make more sense to access `xhr.responseText` directly, instead of stringifying the object that was created by parsing that very response text.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I just meant so that we could all see the data in order to help him know how to handle it

Comment: could you please show us the JSON response (or a stringified object) instead of those structureless property log-lines?

Comment: @Matt I am testing in Chrome and using crypto to do Base64 encryption for username and password not secure but just testing for now.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS The JSON response is available in `xhr.responseText`. The `data` parameter contains the object that is the result of parsing that JSON response. It makes more sense to access the response directly via `xhr.responseText`, instead of stringifying `data`.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I tried alert(JSON.Stringify(data)); but it didn't alert anything.

Comment: It should be `stringify`, not `Stringify`. @mcpDESIGNS accidentally capitalized it.

Comment: But try [@prodigitalson's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586526/parsing-a-json-object-with-multiple-sub-objects#comment16961094_12586526). I think that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are outputting stringifying data and you have inside that an array named data then you need to do data.data[0] instead of data[0].

It would be a little more clear for you if you said:

```
success: function(result, status, xhr){
  var data = result.data;
```

Then data[0] would work just fine.